# how to write a php variable on a mysql query

Tags: php, sql

I need to write my php variables correctly.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM palettes LIMIT '$starting_number, $palettes_per_page'");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want single quotes on your LIMIT parameters.  One way is to use . to concatenate strings.

Since `$starting_number` and `$palettes_per_page` are integers, you do not need to escape them.  If they were strings, wrap them in `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_escape_string` to escape special characters.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query( $con,
             "SELECT * FROM palettes LIMIT " .
             $starting_number .
             "," .
             $palettes_per_page );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quote, because double quote can read variable's value

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM palettes LIMIT $starting_number, $palettes_per_page");
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You could use parameterized queries which also prevent any need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM palettes LIMIT ?, ?'");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $starting_number, $palettes_per_page);
$stmt->execute();`